# Detecting jQuery .stop()

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

I'm creating a jQuery plugin which adds some custom animations to an element and I want to detect when the .stop() method is called on that element. Here is an example:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myAnimation = function() {
        var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
            // Do animation stuff
            if (.stop() == true) {
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            {
        });
    });
});

$(".element").myAnimation();
$(".element").stop();
```

So my question is, how do I do this:

```
if (.stop() == true)
```

Or is there a way to do it with an event handler like this:

```
this.bind("stop", function() {});
```

Or an I going about this completely the wrong way?

Many Thanks
Stephen

Comment: there is no such even as "stop", you can't use it with bind. `.stop()` method returns an object not a Boolean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Until I can find a way to add the jQuery **:animated** selector, I have come up with the following work around:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myAnimation = function() {
        this.addClass("isanimated");
        var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
            // do animation
            if (this.hasClass("isanimated") == false) {
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
});

$(".element").myAnimation();
$(".element").removeClass("isanimated");
```

*Code above not tested.*

If anyone can suggests ways to add the **:animated** selector, I would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are leaking implementation details of your plugin to outside the plugin's scope.

Comment: except the fact that you are leaking details out of the plugin's scope as @alex mentioned, why are you using a combinaison of a recursive function and `clearInterval()` while there are more cleaner ways to make a flag ?

Comment: @Amine I don"t believe that's recursion, it's cancelling the interval.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to check to see if the element is animated. If so, you can use [jQuery's `:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/).

```
if( this.is(':animated') ) {...
```

If you're hoping to cancel the interval, you may just need to build that into the API as a custom method that the user calls which will stop the animation, *and* call `clearInterval`.

Comment: So jQuery would add this selector when an animation begins and then removes it when an animation stops?

Comment: @GateKiller - The selector will match if the element it is called against is currently being animated. When the animation stops, it no longer matches. I updated my answer after taking a closer look at what you appear to want to do. I think the safest road would be to have a method specific to the task of stopping the animation and clearing the interval.

Comment: @Patrick This seems to be exactly what I need. The question is, how do I add the ":animated" selector to the element my custom animation begins?

Comment: @Patrick I've been searching around and still can't find a way to add the :animated selector. If you had any more info it would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: @GateKiller - I'm not sure what you mean about adding the `:animated` selector. If the element is in the process of being animated, the selector will match. If not, it won't. I'll create an example in a minute.

Comment: @GateKiller: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/KCcBf/) of the `:animated` selector working. The result of `.is(':animated')` is `true` while the animation is running. When complete, the result is `false`.

Comment: @Patrick, I understand this part however, I am creating my own animation which doesn't use the jQuery.animate function thus the **:animated** boolean doesn't get applied. I want to know how to add it when I start my custom animation?

Comment: @GateKiller - I see what you mean. Looking at the data that is cached for an animated element, the only change it makes is to add an "inprogress" item to an Array stored under `fxqueue`. You achieve the same "inprogress" by using jQuery's `.queue()`, but it isn't seen as `:animated` when you do. I don't see any other change to any data associated with the element, so perhaps jQuery just tracks it internally without any publicly exposed indicator.

Comment: @GateKiller - After a little more investigation, I see that when an element is animated, a function is added to the `jQuery.timers` array. Calling that function returns true. When the animation is complete, the function is removed. Not sure how jQuery associates the correct element though. Any solution will likely be pretty hacky.

Comment: the `:animated` selector can't tell if `.stop()` has been used by an element only but it also returns true if the element was never animated, thus there's a difference between an element that is not animated and if the same element is being stopped (in the sens of, it was never animated before)

Answer (score 0):

two possible solutions for this :

A) create a flag (2 ways to do that)
B) create a custom event

**A-create a flag**
1-you can use [**`.attr()`**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to add a flag

```
$('.element').stop().attr('stopped','')
//to check use :
if($('.element').is('[stopped]'))
```

2-if you don't want any attribute involved or any changing DOM structure
you can attach a tacit flag.
by using [**`.data()`**](https://api.jquery.com/data/)to store arbitrary data :

```
$(".element").stop().data('stopped',true);
```

then retrieve it for checking purposes

```
if($(".element").data('stopped')) /** (1) **/
```

as for the plugin (as you mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4346610/3423014))
yes we can create one out of it :

```
// Stop() with a capital S, don't have to remind you jQuery is case sensitive
$.fn.Stop = function() {
  this.stop().data('stopped', true)
  return this
} // check the same way as i mentioned in (1)
```

**B-create a custom event**
if you don't want a flag of any type or whatsoever
you can create a custom event, since 'stop' isn't one
[Documentation about creating custom events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/)

```
$('*').on('stop', function() {
  $(this).stop()
  //any other Statements you want
  //in this case you may need to change the selector
  //to match only '.element'
})
```

the event is then triggered using `.trigger()` :

```
$('.element').trigger('stop')
```